# Print all twin prime pairs below 100 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

Write a program to determine how many twin prime pairs there are under 100

```
n = 100 # upper limit number
k = range(3, int((n+1)**0.5) + 1, 2)


def is_prime_pair(i, i2):
if i <= 2 or i2 <= 2:
    return False
max_div = (i2 ** 0.5) + 1
for x in k:
    if (x > max_div or x == i or x == i2):
        break
    if (i % x == 0) or (i2 % x == 0):
        return False
return True
for i in range(1, n+1, 2):
    if is_prime_pair(i, i+2):
        print "(" + str(i) + ", " + str(i+2) + ")" # Print pairs if prime pair
```

How can I optimize my code to make it shorter and faster?

Comment: Does it have be both shorter **and** faster? Can it be shorter, but slower? Can it be faster, but longer?

Comment: Variable `k` is used only once, so it can be replaced in the `for` loop with just the defined range. Also, I believe the `break` can be entirely replaced with `return True` or `return 1`.

Comment: for optimization you would have better luck (or at least less downvotes) at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

> How can i optimize my code to make it shorter and faster ?

Here's sieve-based approach that's a little shorter and a lot faster:

```
def find_prime_pairs(n):

    sieve = [True] * n

    if n > 0:
        sieve[0] = False
        if n > 1:
            sieve[1] = False

    for number in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        if sieve[number]:
            for index in range(number * number, n, number):
                sieve[index] = False

    return [(a, b) for b, a in enumerate(range(0, n - 2), start=2) if sieve[a] and sieve[b]]

print(*find_prime_pairs(100), sep='\n')
```

**USAGE**

```
> python3 test.py
(3, 5)
(5, 7)
(11, 13)
(17, 19)
(29, 31)
(41, 43)
(59, 61)
(71, 73)
>
```

When working with primes up to 100, any code will do, it's too small a range to tax performance.  Let's consider 1000000 (a million) instead.  For timing purposes, we'll count, rather than print, pairs.

The first answer provided by @AlexHall takes twice as long as your original code to count the pairs up to one million.  His second answer takes three times longer than your original code.  Shorter doesn't always mean faster.  Don't trust any answer until you've fully tested it.

My sieve-based code above is four times faster than your original code and 15% smaller.

Answer (score 0):

First build up a list of primes which will then be searched for twins
This way you never check the same number twice for being prime.

```
primes = [2]
for candidate in xrange(3, 100, 2):
    # Secondly don't try dividing potential primes by every odd number
    # Just try dividing by the primes you already know!
    for prime in primes:
        if prime ** 2 > candidate:
            primes.append(candidate)
            break
        if candidate % prime == 0:
            break

# Iterate through all positions in the list except the last to avoid an IndexError
for i in xrange(len(primes) - 1):
    if primes[i + 1] - primes[i] == 2:
        print (primes[i], primes[i + 1])
```

Tuples are formatted the way you want already.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mostly stick to your current code but improve details:

1. Use `for i in range(3, ...` since you know that a prime pair can't start with 1 or 2. Then you can remove `if i <= 2...` because that will never happen.
2. It makes things harder to have an `is_prime_pair` function which is testing for the primality of two numbers at once. Rather have an `is_prime` function which tests a single number and then call `is_prime(i) and is_prime(i+2)`.
3. It's clear that if `x` is not greater than `max_div` then it is less than `i` and `i2` so remove `or x == i or x == i2`. By the way `if (x > max_div or x == i or x == i2):` doesn't need those extra parentheses: `if x > max_div or x == i or x == i2:` is valid.
4. If `x == max_div` then you can `break` already because `max_div` is greater than the square root of `x`.
5. `**` has precedence over `+` so simplify to `max_div = i2 ** 0.5 + 1`.

So now we have:

```
def is_prime(i):
    max_div = i ** 0.5 + 1
    for x in k:
        if x >= max_div:
            break
    ...
```

This is a silly way of doing things: just iterate over a range where `max_div` is the upper bound! You just have to convert `max_div` to an `int` to be allowed in the range function. Convince yourself that this does the correct thing whether `i` is a perfect square or not and that there are no off-by-one errors. Then we have:

```
def is_prime(i):
    max_div = int(i ** 0.5 + 1)
    for x in range(3, max_div, 2):
        if i % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

This is a common pattern that can be refactored conveniently in Python:

```
def is_prime(i):
    max_div = int(i ** 0.5 + 1)
    return not any(i % x == 0 for x in range(3, max_div, 2))
```

(I've used a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) in case you're not familiar with that)

You can make it more concise, though possibly harder to read, with two tricks. First inline `max_div` since it's only used once. Then, instead of `any`, you can use `all` and treat ints as booleans:

```
def is_prime(i):
    return all(i % x for x in range(3, int(i ** 0.5 + 1), 2))
```

Here we're saying that a number is prime if it leaves some nonzero remainder when divided by `x` *for all `x`* (hence the `all` function) worth checking. This works because in Python `0` is like `False` and all other numbers are like `True`.

As mentioned in my other answer, there's no need to format the pair manually.

Since you used `print` as a statement you must be using Python 2, not 3 as your tag says. In that case replace all instances of `range` with `xrange` for efficiency.

So in the end it's just:

```
n = 100  # upper limit number

def is_prime(i):
    return all(i % x for x in xrange(3, int(i ** 0.5 + 1), 2))

for i in xrange(3, n + 1, 2):
    if is_prime(i) and is_prime(i + 2):
        print (i, i + 2)
```

However I'm confident that my other answer is faster, although this probably won't show for just `n = 100`. The most glaring problem is that whenever `i` is prime, then `is_prime(i + 2)` will be called and then `is_prime(i)` in the next iteration of the loop will be redundant as that was just calculated. You can improve on this by memoizing `is_prime` using a set.

Answer (score 0):

```
def prime(i):
""" This function finds whether a number is prime or not?"""
val=False
for n in range(2,i):
    if i%n==0:
            break;
else:
    val=True
return val
for x in range(2,1000):
if prime(x)==True & prime(x+2)==True:
    print("{} and {} are prime twins".format(x,x+2))
```

This should help. First I define a function whether it is prime or not. Next I use that function to find twin primes within a range by taking x and x+2 into comparison. x being each number in that range.

Comment: How does this help?  The OP wants to optimize his solution to make it shorter and faster.  Although yours is shorter, on my system the OP's code takes a fraction of a second to process up to 100,000 but yours takes a minute and a half!  Did you take the time to understand the OP's question, code and any existing answers?  Who upvoted this and why?